# Как настроить андроид эмулятор на qt creator?

Tags: android, qtcreator, эмулятор

Всем привет. Подскажите как я могу исправить ошибки с openSSL при настройке андроид эмулятора на ubuntu 22. Делаю всё по примеру из ютуба, но у меня не так выходит. Не могу настроить openSSL и добавить устройство
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при чём тут эмулятор? укажите путь для openssl у себя дома и скачайте его кнопкой `Загрузить OpenSSL`, логично указать `/home/ahmed/Android/OpenSSL`

Comment: Пробовал, но ошибка не исчезает

Comment: что значит не исчезает? OpenSSL скачивается?

Comment: Да, но два пункта всё равно красным светятся.

Comment: странно, посмотрите в скачанном, у меня там оба эти файла лежат

Comment: Вот отсюда qtc скачивает https://github.com/KDAB/android_openssl